# WebApi works locally but when published It fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have a webapi which works fine locally with Postman - but when published to remote server postman returns:

> "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path
>   was not found"

The WebAPi accepts POST only, and connects to a Remote Database via EF 6.

Any ideas what is wrong, why it works locally but not remotely?

Comment: Because your database connection string points to local server?

Comment: @tia make your comment the answer and you will get the points! I cannot believe I was being so dumb - I was using an internal IP and not the public! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite general, but it seems like your database server is not reachable from the remote server. I guess it might be that your connection string currently points to your local server instead of production server.